# Combine dates for different id when start and end is in different rows and columns

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-difference

I have a table where one person has several rows of different sessions with start and end dates. The end date in first row can be the same as the start date in the next row, and therefore I want to combine these in to one row, since the session actually continues. Im using MySQL, but version 5.7 and an upgrade to use a later version is not possible.

This is an example of what I have: ****Edit with example where the same user has multiple sessions:

```sql
create table dates (USER_ID varchar(100),
                         start datetime,
                         end datetime);

insert into dates values ('1','2014-06-01','2014-07-01');
insert into dates values ('1','2014-07-01','2014-08-01');
insert into dates values ('1','2014-08-01','2014-09-01');
insert into dates values ('2','2014-07-01','2014-08-01');
insert into dates values ('2','2014-08-01','2014-09-01');
insert into dates values ('2','2014-10-01','2014-11-01');

+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| USER_ID | start               | end                 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1       | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 | 2014-07-01 00:00:00 |
| 1       | 2014-07-01 00:00:00 | 2014-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 1       | 2014-08-01 00:00:00 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 2       | 2014-07-01 00:00:00 | 2014-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 2       | 2014-08-01 00:00:00 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 2       | 2014-10-01 00:00:00 | 2014-11-01 00:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

This is what I want, instead of just the min/max date for each USER_ID

```sql
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| USER_ID | start               | end                 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1       | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 2       | 2014-07-01 00:00:00 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 2       | 2014-10-01 00:00:00 | 2014-11-01 00:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: . . I don't think your sample data does a good job representing your problem.  You should show an example where the same user has multiple sessions in the result set.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the example

Answer (score 1):

use aggregation and group by

```
select user_id, min(start) as start, max(end) as end
from tablename
group by user_id
```

Comment: Not fully what I want, now I will only obtain the min and max dates, but the same user can have multiple sessions. Sorry, my example was unclear in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  I recommend solving this one by using a left join to identify where the islands start and then aggregate:

```
select user_id, min(start), max(end)
from (select t.*,
             sum(tprev.user_id is null) over (partition by t.user_id order by t.start) as grp
      from t left join
           t tprev
           on tprev.user_id = t.user_id and
              tprev.end = t.start
     ) t
group by user_id, grp;
```

This solution uses window functions, which have been available since the release of MySQL 8.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting syntax error from this. I am using MySQL.

Comment: I have an earlier version of MySQL unfortunately. 5.7

Comment: @user11152908 . . . Much, much harder without window functions.  I might suggest that you upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible in my case, but thanks anyway!